# How to extract selective text from word document uploaded on Share point site as attachment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ifilter

How to extract selective text from word document uploaded on Share point site as attachment.
If a word document is added as attachment - how do we extract selected text from the word document

Comment: Please add more context. Where do you want this selective text to be extracted? Is there a separate standalone program/ job?

Comment: The selective text is to be extracted from the uploaded word document (attachment) to be inserted or presented into an excel sheet. Presently there is no program to extract the selected text - Are there some tools/ functionality inherent to Share Point like iFilter etc to extract the text from attached word document into another file.